# Exception in constructor: init() method, pointers, large try/catch or..?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I am dealing with an object constructor that can throw an error. I have the following options.

1) Have a very large `try` block that encloses all the code that needs the object (because of the object scope):

```
try {
  Object a(input_vars); // This can throw
  // Do 
  // loads of stuff 
  // with a here
} catch (exception e) {
  // Do something with exception    
}
```

I am not particularly comfortable with this, as it would include a very large code portion. Still, perhaps the most appealing of the options here.

2) Move the throw to an init() method:

```
Object a(input_vars); // This one does not throw
try {
  a.init(); // Only this one can throw
} catch (exception e) {
  // Do something with exception (EDIT: and terminate)
}

// Do some stuff with a
```

This however causes the object to be half-constructed, requires people to remember to call init(), and violates Resource acquisition is initialization (RAII).

3) Only use pointers:

```
Object* a;
try {
  a = new Object(input_vars); // This one can throw
} catch (exception e) {
  // Do something with exception (EDIT: and terminate)
}

// Do some stuff with a

delete a;
```

This would require remembering to destroy the object. It also add risks with dandling pointers etc.

Which one of the options above would you prefer and for which reason? Are there any other options I haven't thought about?

Comment: If I'm correct, the 3rd one is not the dangling pointer, but memory leak, because the memory isn't deallocated after `new` and `throw`.

Comment: Both 2 and 3 have you "do some stuff" with an object that failed to construct, and thus *doesn't exist* (in a usable state anyway). How do you expect that code to cope with it?

Comment: @Quentin Fair enough. In my mind the exception will always exit the program. I now realise that's a bit stupid..

Comment: @GoverNator Yep, corrected seconds before you posted :)

Comment: if you are not particular comfortable with having a large portion of code inside the try, put it inside a function that takes the Object as parameter

Comment: Regarding the third alternative. The big issue is that you seem to attempt to use `a` even if the constructor threw an exception, which of course will lead to UB. The problem with destroying the object could be solved with [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). The first alternative is what I would personally go for.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1) is correct. Reason: when the constructor throws, the object `a` has failed to construct and thus does not exist in any valid state. The following code which uses `a` would either have to be written to account for this possibility all the time, or it had better be skipped altogether.

Comment: +1. And to avoid the issue that the comments in the code hint at, "Do loads of stuff with `a` here", write another function and call it from inside the `try` block.